# email template outlook doesn't know its outlook

Tags: email, outlook

Im trying to make an email template. I am trying to test how it looks in various browsers etc.

I tried using:

```xml
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    this should show everywhere except outlook
<!--<![endif]-->
   and
<!--[if mso]>
   this should show in Outlook only
<![endif]-->
```

I tried looking in gmail, outlook (App), Outlook (browser) and windows Mail app.

For some reason I am getting "this should show everywhere except outlook" on all of them. the second line doesn't show up at all.

I should note that I am using a chrome extension to test these emails - HTML inserter for Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo Mail.

Is there another way to test this? Does anyone know why this isn't working?